# The way to find profile(s) with only Read access on Account

Tags: profile

Let's say we are near to create new profile but before there is need to verify that there are not such ones in org. How can we do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can verify this with a simple query:

```
SELECT Profile.Name
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT ParentId 
  FROM ObjectPermissions 
  WHERE PermissionsCreate = true AND 
    PermissionsEdit = false AND 
    sObjectType = 'Account')
  AND IsOwnedByProfile = true
```

This will give you all of the profiles where your desired conditions are met.

You can run this query directly from Developer Console (⚙ > Developer Console in Lightning, "Your Name" > Developer Console in Classic, or Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Developer Console) on the Query Editor tab.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to filter somehow records related to Account only?

Comment: @pincet Yes, you can add `AND sObjectType = 'Account'` in the subquery.